# Invoking a CodeActivity from another CodeActivity under the same Context

Tags: tfs, build, workflow

I have two custom activity(CodeActivity) classes that derived from CodeActivity. One activity is placed on the TFS build process template(xaml). This CodeActivity is calling my other custom CodeActivity using WorkflowInvoker.Invoke method. When I call the second CodeActivity, it's being called under different CodeActivityContext. Why is that? For that reason, when I write message into second CodeActivity's Context, its not shown in build process. Is there any way to call the second codeActivity under my first CodeActivity's CodeActivityContext? My Second CodeActivity also calls another custom CodeActivity. I want to call all of them in the same CodeActivityContext. How can I do that? 
Can anybody help me please?

NOTE: All of my CodeActivity is derived from one base class of CodeActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible to derive from [NativeActivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.nativeactivity.aspx)? Then you can use the [ScheduleAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781359.aspx) method from the [NativeActivityContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.nativeactivitycontext.aspx). That's what we did for our custom activities that had to invoke other activities (child activities that where dropped onto this activity).

Comment: Yes, but my understanding is NativeActivity is for async activity.

Comment: @faizullah: TFS invokes each activity in the build template asynchronously.